# How to set the second that eventBridge events trigger at?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-event-bridge

I can trigger and [EventBridge](https://www.serverless.com/) (rule/schedule feature [formerly](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/upgrading-to-amazon-eventbridge-from-amazon-cloudwatch-events/) in CloudWatch) scheduled function with a rate (say, once-every 5 minutes) or via a cron setup to do the same.

And the rate-setting will routinely trigger at:
7:05:13, 7:10:13, 7:15:13, etc.

If I delete the EventBridge rule and rebuild it, it will trigger at:
7:05:42, 7:10:42, 7:15:42, etc...

My guess is that it starts at the second that the rule first goes into effect and just dutifully tiggers at that rate.

I need to trigger at exactly the same second - preferably the zeroth second or some other very-close-to-zero value because I'm doing syncronized data collection with another process that DOES collect on the zeroth second - is there a way to define the start second of a EventBridge scheduled task rule (particularly helpful would be if there was a way to do it with the [serverless framework](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjbhqXRhcP0AhVPl3IEHUfLCwoQFnoECAoQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.serverless.com%2F&usg=AOvVaw2mHOLTv5R09wmvc0meSNwK))?

I've tried with a cron setup and had the same basic results (different seconds, of course, but still not the zeroth second - and the second it fired changed on every deployment of the rule)

Shy of ensuring my enterprise-scale [serverless framework](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjbhqXRhcP0AhVPl3IEHUfLCwoQFnoECAoQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.serverless.com%2F&usg=AOvVaw2mHOLTv5R09wmvc0meSNwK) deployment goes out at the zeroth-second every time (something that's not reasonable for a large-scale multi-member project) how can I set the second-level timing of a cron or rate-based rule task in eventBridge (formerly cloudwatch)?

Previous questions ([How can I schedule cloudwatch rule at second level?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67849196/how-can-i-schedule-cloudwatch-rule-at-second-level)) have implied that the default is that things trigger at the zeroth second, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: Please don't include Google redirect links. Just include the target page's link.

Comment: Would it be viable to trigger a Lambda one minute early, and then wait until the 00 second to do whatever it is you need to. Will waste 30 seconds on average, but probably not terrible.

Comment: It might be a better idea to have this other service trigger the lambda instead.

Comment: This lambda actually gets triggered once a minute and lasts around 5-10 seconds (it's pulling async data from a different api).... Doing it on the 'prior minute' and waiting would effectively mean I'd have a lambda running 24/7.... that's ... less than ideal.

Answer (score 1):

EventBridge does not provide second accuracy.
It does not guarantee the execution at exact minute/seconds, even though you observe it.

If you need execution at second accuracy, then EventBridge is not the right tool for you.

As noted here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/ScheduledEvents.html

> CloudWatch Events does not provide second-level precision in schedule
> expressions. The finest resolution using a cron expression is a
> minute. Due to the distributed nature of the CloudWatch Events and the
> target services, the delay between the time the scheduled rule is
> triggered and the time the target service honors the execution of the
> target resource might be several seconds. Your scheduled rule is
> triggered within that minute, but not on the precise 0th second.

Comment: "then EventBridge is not the right tool for you." -- suggestions for alternative solutions?

Comment: I would probably run a separate permanent docker container with a scheduler like https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ which would invoke lamba. lambda has to be provisionned for concurrency to reduce warmup latency that may be several seconds itself.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by simply have eventbridge fire a lambda that does nothing other than 'wait' for the zeroth second... and then invokes my actual lambda.

Comment: Why would you want to incur unnecessary cost. For a relatively simple thing.

Comment: @HimanshuRawat Is there another solution that provides second-level startups of lambdas?